# adding c++ library giac/xcas to iOS project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I've never included a C++ library in an iOS project before. Therefore I do not have so much experience with setting specific parameters. I want to use the giac CAS library from this site: [https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/giac.html](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Eparisse/giac.html) .

What have I done so far:

- copied libtommath files and dragged into my project
- copied all c++ and c header files from giac/src and dragged into my project
- copied config.h.iphone to config.h
- In build settings I changed C++ Standard Library to libstdc++ (GNU
  C++ standard library)
- In Header Search Paths and Library Search Paths I added gmp.h via the
  entry /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.2.1/include/**
- In Other Linker flags I added the entry "-lgmp"

Before trying to add an Objective-C++ class to expose functions from giac, I want to see if it could be built.

But I get the error "cstddef file not found" in file first.h  Do I have to make other settings ?

Comment: Do you have a solution to your problem?